# how does hard link and soft link works

Tags: linux

The concept is quite hard for me to understand.

I get it that hard link points to the the same file so they have the same size as the original file and soft links are text based and point to the place of the wanted file.

What i don't get is why when you point to a file with a hard link and then you suppress the original file the hardlink still represent the file and the files still exists then ?

I know that when you delete a file it's not really deleted it just says that there is empty space here where you can write on so the file is still here despite i suppressed it , so i think that pressuring a file just means deleting the pointer to it and not the file itself and that's why it's faster to delete then copy a file.

A file will always keep existing as long as at least one link still point to it , so because the hardlink is directly connected to  the file it will not be deleted and will take the name of the second link.

But if it's a soft link we just have a text file that show the directory of the wanted file so it have no rapport on the state of the original file , that's my theory i hope that someone explain and correct me.

Comment: maybe this is interesting for you http://askubuntu.com/questions/108771/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: Related, possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/299498/what-is-a-hard-link-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

> What i don't get is why when you point to a file with a hard link and then you suppress the original file the hardlink still represent the file and the files still exists then ?

Hardlinks are basically just names attached to an inode, and the original name you give to a new file is a hardlink as well. So if you delete the original, you aren't actually "suppressing the original file" – you're just deleting its original hardlink.

The "remove file" syscall is also called `unlink(2)` – see [Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) or [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unlink&sektion=2) docs.

> A file will always keep existing as long as at least one link still point to it , so because the hardlink is directly connected to  the file it will not be deleted and will take the name of the second link.

As above. Hardlinks *are* essentially just names for the file. So if it has two hardlinks (original and additionally created), then it has two names.

(On most Unix systems, files with no links (no names) can also exist – as long as a process keeps a handle to it. It's a common trick used with temporary files: create a large file in /tmp and immediately unlink it.)

> But if it's a soft link we just have a text file that show the directory of the wanted file so it have no rapport on the state of the original file

Sounds about right.

Comment: thanks , can you tell me a little more about this inodes ? so when i'm looking at my directeries the hdd doesn't search for the files it only loads all the links he could find that's why navigation is so fast ? also if i have like 4 links and i suppress the original how will the pc choose the next official file name , if i have both hard and soft links for a file what link will the pc work on with

Comment: There isn't such a thing as "the official file name". All hardlinks – both the original and the later-created ones – are _equally_ 'official'.

Comment: thanks it was just a way of saying the name that is now the one who is displayed or the first name of the file

Comment: But they're all displayed identically. There is no "first" name.

Comment: but when you display the files , it chooses at least one name , and that's the first that was ever assigned to it no ?

Comment: No. (Have you actually _tried_ using links?) Every time you create a link, it shows up as _its own_ entry in the directory, doesn't it? So if you have a file with 4 links, `ls` already shows 4 items in the directory. Deleting _any_ one of them still leaves you with 3 items. [Like this.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d70b5737b27710d3397e0cf24271ad12)